# How can I convert .py to .exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Recently, I found pingpong game made by pygame and I am trying to convert it into .exe file but i can't. this is the link of the code I am trying to convert. https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/pygame-pong/ (this site is japanese, the code is at middle)

Thank you for your helps!!

Comment: There is [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Answer (score 2):

[pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) is compatible with up to python 3.6.

> Install PyInstaller from PyPI:
>
> `pip install pyinstaller`
>
> Go to your program’s directory and run:
>
> `pyinstaller yourprogram.py`

Answer (score 1):

There are different tools for converting a python script into an executable. For example:

http://py2exe.org/